# How to have a textarea at 100% width and keep its margin?

Tags: html, css

Given the following CSS

```css
.comment {
    margin: 10px;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 1px 1px 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    min-height: 200px;
    width: 100% 
}
```

This is applied to a `textarea` but the right margin is ignored and the `textarea` goes off the screen.

why is this?

Comment: Can you show how your HTML is structured?

Comment: Are you trying to make the textarea width fluid?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By setting the width to 100% and a margin of 10px the textarea will be a 100% width of it's container shifted down and to the left 10px

To get your desired result you'll probably need to use a container around the textarea with a 10px padding.

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/DY6L6/1/).

- commentA is using a container with padding
- commentB is your original CSS

so something like:

```
<div class="comment-container">
    <textarea class="commentA"></textarea>
</div>
```

and

```
.comment-container {
    padding:10px;
}
.commentA {
    width:100%;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

to get started.

Comment: I had to use 'margin: 10px' rather than padding for it to work. But the put it in a container was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
display: inline
```

Instead of:

```
display: block
```